# нумерация значений input'ов в цикле

Tags: php

Пользователь задает $points - это число точек. У меня есть цикл, в нем есть inputы. По мере выполнения цикла от цифр 1 до $points, я хочу, чтобы в value всех этих инпутов были соответствующие названия.

```
elseif ($authors_points_name == 'нет') {
for ($iter = 1; $iter <= $points ; $iter++) { 
    ?>
        <label>Точка отгрузки № <? echo $iter; ?>, присвойте ей новое название: </label><input type="text" name="<? echo "B" . $iter; ?>" value ='<? echo "B" . $iter; ?>'> <br>
    <?
}
}
```

То есть чтобы пользователю не нужно было вручную вводить каждое название от 1 до 100, к примеру, компьютер бы сам пронумеровал их по типу B1 B2 B3 ... B100. Я написал следующий код,  но значения не хотят вставляться. Как мне сделать задуманное?

Comment: да, вроде, все вставляется :) - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a549b0575c2de3781a7f79b123e9cd853307cde2

Comment: @splash58 точно, у меня же B1 B2, а type стоял numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

elseif ($authors_points_name == 'нет') {
for ($iter = 1; $iter <= $points ; $iter++) { 

        echo '<label>Точка отгрузки № '.$iter.', присвойте ей новое название: </label><input type="text" name="B'.$iter.'" value ="B '.$iter.'"><br>';

}
}
?>
```